# ¿Es correcto utilizar EBS para almacenar un Wordpress en AWS?

Tags: aws

Necesito migrar un sitio a AWS, este sitio tiene mucho contenido multimedia (~40GB). ¿Es posible crear un volumen de EBS (~100GB) y montarlo en /var/www/html usando una instancia EC2 (~10GB) ?

¿Cómo puedo calcular un precio estimado de esto utilizando la [calculadora de AWS](https://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html)? No comprendo sus parámetros de Data Transfer (In, Out)

¿Existe una mejor manera de lograr esto y que sea económico?

¿Es correcta la elección de EBS sobre S3 en este caso?

Answer (score 1):

Depende de tu uso esperado.

S3 te cobra por:

- Espacio Utilizado por mes (GB/mes)
- Transferencia de datos (cuantos ingresan y egresan)
- Peticiones GET/PUT/POST/LIST etc.

EBS te cobra por:

- Espacio del Volumen
- Rendimiento deseado (si es superior al rendimiento base)

Por ejemplo, de la calculadora:

```
  100GB de datos de S3
+ 10,000 peticiones GET
+ 1,000 peticiones PUT/POST/LIST etc.
+ 100 GB/mes de ingreso de datos
+ 100 GB/mes de egreso de datos
 = 16.83 USD/mes para la region de US-East
```

Por otro lado, en EBS:

```
100GB de General Purpose SDD (con rendimiento base de 128MB/sec)
= $9.18 USD/mes para la region de US-East
```

Además, al EBS tendrías que sumarle el costo del respaldo (snapshots) si es que te interesa.

En mi opinión personal, si vas a utilizar el espacio para almacenar estáticos, y no planeas estar manipulándolos mucho (borrando, reemplazando) una vez creados, S3 es mucho mejor opción. Ya cuenta con respaldos y redundancia, además que si requieres de mucho rendimiento (throughput) es probable que en algun punto satures el IOPS del SSD a menos que pagues por ello (y entonces será todavía más caro.)

Podrías incluso reducir el costo de S3 utilizando el Reduced Redundancy Storage (si los estáticos que tengas no son absolutamente críticos y puedes considerar la opción de perderlos... aunque en realidad es muy poco probable: [99.99% vs 99.999999999%](https://aws.amazon.com/es/s3/reduced-redundancy/?nc1=f_ls))

Espero esto te ayude a tomar la mejor decisión.

Answer (score 0):

> ¿Cómo puedo calcular un precio estimado de esto utilizando la calculadora de AWS? No comprendo sus parámetros de Data Transfer (In, Out)

Efectivamente, para poder calcular el precio adecuadamente no solo debes conocer cuanto ocupará, es necesario además saber cual es el tráfico que tu contenido multimedia supone.

> ¿Existe una mejor manera de lograr esto y que sea económico?

Sin duda S3 es una opción más económica por varios motivos.

- Como menciono más abajo, está optimizado para el acceso vía web con una alta durabilidad y a un coste muy reducido. Aunque los precios varían ligeramente de una región a otra, puedes ver [aquí](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/) una referencia para las capas principales de persistencia (*glacier* es solo para backups finales, no para servir contenido)
- Si tu sitio web tiene mucho tráfico, es más que probable que acabes poniendo un balanceador de carga (Elastic Load Balancer) y consumir tráfico (a coste no reducido) por dicho balanceador para tus fichero estáticos si que sería a largo plazo mucho más caro que el uso de un CDN para este tipo de contenidos.

> ¿Es correcta la elección de EBS sobre S3 en este caso?

En casos como el tuyo (servir contenido estático de una web), no hay duda de que lo que se *recomienda* es **usar S3** (o cualquier otro servicio CDN en general) por varios motivos que considero fundamentados más allá de mi opinión:

1. Esta **diseñado para este tipo de accesos** por clave (url fichero) - valor (contenido del fichero). Sea cual sea el tipo de fichero estático: vídeos, imágenes, css, js, etc, etc.
2. Va a **aliviar la carga de tu servidor web** dado que todo el contenido estático (multimedia) será servido en adelante desde S3 y no desde tu servidor.Esto hará que sea más robusto frente a pico de acceso y al uso
3. **Múltiples capas de persistencia** (transparentes para ti) adaptadas a la frecuencia de acceso (y por tanto más económicas).
4. Posee **reglas automatizadas** para realizar transiciones de una capara de persistencia a otra, por ejemplo puedes determinar que los ficheros que tengan más X meses/años, pasen a una capa de persistencia más económica dado que sabes que van a ser menos accedidos.
5. Alta redundancia (transparente para ti) y a bajo coste. Puedes hacer copias de seguridad automáticamente pero S3 ya te garantiza una durabilidad de 99.999999999% con varias copias internas de tus datos.
6. Escala de manera **indefinida** e **ilimitada**. A diferencia de EBS. no vas a tener que preocuparte **nunca** de si vas a quedarte sin espacio o de tener que redimensionar tu solución.
7. S3 se integra automáticamente con otro servicios dentro del marco AWS. En tu caso más interesante sería **CloudFront**, se trata de un CDN que permitiría un acceso mucho más rápido a tu contenido estático al poseer puntos de localización y chache por todo el planeta, a diferencia de S3 (que quedará fijado a la región inicial que tu decidas).
8. S3 está incluido en la que se denomina **capa gratuita** de AWS por lo que los primeros 5G de almacenamiento, 20.000 get y 2.000 put al mes serán gratuitos durante el primer año.
9. Para tu caso concreto existen **numerosos plugins** que se integran con S3. [Aquí](https://wordpress.org/plugins/tags/s3/) puedes verlos. Yo personalmente, he usado *W3 Total Cache* con bastante buen resultado.

Por otro lado EBS es un servicio de almacenamiento que podría entenderse como **discos duros virtuales**, está más diseñado para alojar sistemas operativos, bases de datos, etc.

Aunque la pregunta está orientada a S3 y EBS insisto en la importancia de usar un CDN para esta finalidad y te recomiendo que leas [este](https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/tips-tricks/best-cdn-services-for-wordpress-users) artículo para que veas la variedad existente y la importancia de usar un CDN para servir tu contenido estático.

Answer (score 0):

Yo me voy por usar s3 y una distribución de cloudFront,  es muy válido las anteriores respuestas y tienes que validar con que frecuencia cambian los archivos y si tu app va a escalar.
En mi experiencia he usado EFS para almacenar archivoa de configuración en un ambiente con autoacaling y s3 junto con CloudFront para todo el contenido(imágenes,  video....)